# minizipで解凍した実体がどこにあるのかわかりません。

Tags: objective-c, c++

下記ソースコードでメソッドから[minizip](https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip)のunzip.cにある
unzOpen2メソッドをバイトデータを解凍したところ、
圧縮前のサイズと一致している事はunz64local_GetCurrentFileInfoInternalメソッドの
file_info.uncompressed_sizeで確認できたのですが
解析しても解凍後のデータがどこに保存されているのかわからず悩んでおります。

ZipFormatのように、特定のビットにデータが格納されるのでしょうか？
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%29
　
開発環境：MacOSX 10.10.3、xCode6.3.2、Objective-c

```
void uncompressByGzip(const char** ptrSrc, const int srcLength)
{
    unz64_s unz64data;
    unzFile unzfiledata;

    unsigned long long int readdatasize;

    zlib_filefunc_def filefunc32 = {0};
    ourmemory_t unzmem = {0};

    unzmem.size = srcLength;
    unzmem.base = (char *)malloc(unzmem.size);
    memcpy(unzmem.base, ptrSrc, unzmem.size);

    fill_memory_filefunc(&filefunc32, &unzmem);
    unzfiledata = unzOpen2("__notused__", &filefunc32);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unzOpen2()を実行しただけでは解凍できません。
minizipでzip内のファイルを解凍するには以下の手順が必要です。

(1) zipファイルをオープンする。

```
unzfiledata = unzOpen2(...)
```

(2) zip 内の解凍したいファイルPATHを指定する。

```
unzLocateFile(unzfiledata, ...)
```

zip内に1ファイルしかない場合は、

```
unzGoToFirstFile(unzfiledata)
```

(3) (2)で指定したzip内のファイルをオープンする

```
unzOpenCurrentFile(unzfiledata)
```

(4) (3)でオープンしたzip内のファイルを読取バッファに読み込む

```
unzReadCurrentFile(unzfiledata, ...)
```

(5) (3)でオープンしたzip内のファイルをクローズする。

```
unzCloseCurrentFile(unzfiledata)
```

※zip内の複数ファイルを読みたい場合は(2)～(5)を取得するzip内のファイル数分繰り返す。

(6) (1)でオープンしたzipファイルをクローズする。

```
unzClose(unzfiledata)
```

※zipは複数ファイルを格納可能なためzip内のどのファイルを処理対象とするか(この質問の場合は読み込みたいか)を指定する必要があります。

Comment: メモリーからメモリーへ解凍する時にも同様の手続きで可能でしょうか？
Httpでダウンロードしてきたデータをそのまま使用するのでファイルパスの指定ができません。

Comment: (1) まではできているので(2)以降を行えばよいです。(4)のunzReadCurrentFile()でメモリーに取得できます。